# Is it possible to make remote-specific .gitignores?

Tags: git, github, heroku, gitignore

I use two services, GitHub and Heroku. I have set up remotes for each of the repositories online. However, I want one file to be pushed to Heroku, but not pushed to GitHub. Is there an easy way to do this without having to edit .gitignore every time I push to a different service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like VonC said, it's not natively supported to do what you're asking.

I think the best way to do this would be to have different branches.

For example, you would have your `master` branch, a `github` branch, and a `heroku` branch.

Anything that is synonymous between the two branches would be located in `master`, and anything specific to `github` or `heroku` would be in their respective branches.

Comment: This is what I will be going for. Thanks!

Comment: don't forget to *rebase* your repository dependend branches after each commit to `maser` or at least before pushing to the respective remote.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an easy way to do this without having to edit .gitignore every time I push to a different service?

This is not a native Git feature.
A better option would be to store a `.gitgignore.heroku` file, and have a hook which would be able, on receiving a push, or when deploying on heroku, to detect, copy and rename that `.gitgignore.heroku` into the working tree as `.gitgignore`.

In other words, this is a deployment issue, not a version control one.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. The .gitignore file more or less tells git which files to to include into the commit. It has no effect on which files are pushed. You can only push complete commits, since the commits are defined by the files included.